# how to get data from map in controller SPRING MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jquery, spring-mvc

how to get data from map in controller SPRING MVC

Please help me how to get data map in controler SPRING MVC i put the data map to  like that
map.put("error", "x");

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
     function doAjaxPostTeamDelete (team_ID){


         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/controller/deleteTeam",
            data: "teamID=" + team_ID,          
            success: function(response){  
                  // we have the response  
                ****if(x="${error}")//that is point the i have doubt**** 
                                {
                    alert("You Cant Delete");   
                             }      

                }, 
                error: function(e){  
                  alert('Error: ' + e);  
                }    
         });     
     }   
 </script>
```

this is my controller##

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteTeam", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editDeleteRecodes(@ModelAttribute NewTeams newTeams, Map<String, Object> map){        
        Teams teams = new Teams();
        teams.setTeamID(newTeams.getTeamID());
        try{
            teamService.delete(teams);
        }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){
            map.put("error", "x");
            //System.out.println("aaaaa");
        }

        return "redirect:/";


    }
```

Comment: Post your Controller method also

Comment: Hey i Edit now..thanks lot for your quick answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/deleteTeam", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public String getByIdFromParam(@RequestParam Long teamID) {
         try{
                teamService.delete(new Teams().setTeamID(teamID));
            }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){
                return "error";
            }
            return "sucess";
        }
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function doAjaxPostTeamDelete (team_ID){
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/controller/deleteTeam",
            data: "teamID=" + team_ID,          
            success: function(response){  
                if(response="error"){
                    alert("You Cant Delete");   
                }}, 
            error: function(e){  
                alert('Error: ' + e);  
            }    
         });     
     }   
 </script>
```

Also don't forget to put  [Jackson JSON Processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in classpath

Comment: ah thanks lot it working supper..but stil i have doubt..it is like this..i have 2 table .they are one to n mapping..tables are TEAM and RELEASES ..every TEAM have more RELEASES..then I want, some one going to delete TEAM it shud go to cath and then i can give popup..now what ever i do ..it goes to CATCH..

Comment: @user2991030 Please post it as a new question with relevant code.

Comment: and i didnt add Jackson JSON Processor

Comment: oh. sorry.. Jackson JSON Processor  is necessary only if you use RequestBody instead of RequestParam